# Why would my Win10 PC use Guest account when it is disabled?

Tags: windows, file-sharing

Setting up a new Win10 PC , and connecting to familiar network shares, one of which was on Win8, I encountered this situation:

- Win10 PC:

  - Computer Management -> Users & Groups -> shows Guest account is disabled
  - User NOT logged in as Guest (obviously...)
  - No credentials of any sort registered for the Win8 PC
- Win8 PC:

  - sharing several folders (including one suspicious one)
  - Computer Management -> Users & Groups -> shows Guest account is NOT disabled
  - Control Panel -> User Accounts & Family Safety -> User Accounts -> Manage Accounts reports that "Guest account is off". (Really?)
  - Computer Management -> System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Sessions... showed that there was an active session from the Win10 PC from "Guest"

The Win10 PC is still being set up (4 days old), and the only use of "Guest" so far has been to disable the Guest account. There is no domain - all accounts are local. There are no users but me. How/why would there be any use of "Guest" to access shares on another PC? I can't rule out slips of the mouse, but I can rule out slips of the keyboard that would have typed "guest". As far as I am aware, this occurred on the first attempt to access the Win8 PC shares.

Also, is the conflict between views of the guest account on the Win8 PC any indication of anything sinister... or just poor implementation Microsoft's part?

I ask since we encountered a suspicious share among the Win8 shares - selected parts of the Users folder was shared (nobody knows how or why). That share was accessible to "Guest". The other shares were not accessible to Guest, but since Guest had an active session, we could not access them. We killed the session, disabled Guest which forced a prompt for credentials... but deep suspicions remain about whether this could have occurred legitimately.

Comment: Did you test if you can actually access something using Guest account ?

Comment: Yes - we could access anything in the "users" share that should not have been there in the first place.

Comment: Did you scan the machines with some sort of anti-malware software?

Comment: Maybe password protected shares is off and the share is completely free like XP-era was possible.

Comment: But what would have caused it to decide to use "Guest" without being directed to - is that "normal" in any sense?

Comment: Quick scan showed nothing; updated to latest definitions and still doing full scan as I need to leave...